# Multi module test code reuse

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multi module Android Studio project composed of 3 modules:

1. **app** (regular and unit-test configs) - contains main app code and tests
2. **common** (regular and unit-test configs) - contains common code and tests that are shared with another app
3. **common-testing** (regular config only) - contains common testing utility code used in the tests of the other 2 modules

Now **common-testing (regular)** depends on **common (regular)** for certain classes. This gets dicey in the **common (unit-test)** configuration, where a circular dependency develops. The dependencies for that case are mapped below:

- **common (unit-test)** depends on **common (regular)**
- **common (unit-test)** depends on **common-testing (regular)** depends on **common (regular)**

Unfortunately the last line is a circular dependency (common depends on common), and the project fails to evaluate.

Is there a way to instruct Gradle to break out of a circular dependency? Some sort of include guard like in C/C++?

If not, are there alternate ways of organizing the project to successfully share test code (like runners) between modules?